# ¿Cómo se describe la temperatura?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, tiempo-meteorológico

Cuando se describe el tiempo, se usa "hace", por ejemplo, "hace frío" o "hace sol". ¿Es lo mismo con la temperatura?

Si es la temperatura de algo, como una persona o comida, ¿es lo mismo?

Comment: `hace sol` sounds just wrong to me and so as `hace luna`.

Comment: @César in Spain "hace sol" is one of the most common ways of saying "it's sunny"

Comment: @Juanillo I know, in Perú we use it too. But is it correct? How about `(El día) está soleado`? `hace calor` would be better if we are talking about temperature.

Comment: @César From RAE definition of "hacer": "35. impers. Expresa la cualidad o estado del tiempo atmosférico. Hace calor, frío, buen día Hace bueno Mañana hará malo". So it's correct. I don't really know why you think it's not. Of course you can also say "El día está soleado" but it doesn't mean that "hace sol" is wrong. http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=hacer

Comment: Ahy una parte de colombia y en argentina que se dice `Esta haciendo fresco`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the weather we use the verb "hacer" in an impersonal use (the sentence doesn't have subject)

> **Hace** frío --> It is cold
>
> **Hace** sol --> It is sunny

For the temperature, we use the verb "haber" also in an impersonal way (if you are referring for the environment temperature):

> **Hay** 17 grados (centígrados) (It is 37ºC)

you can also use alternatives like these:

> **Tenemos** un día soleado (centígrados) (we have a sunny day)
>
> Hoy **tenemos** 17 grados (centígrados) (Today it is 37ºC)
>
> Hoy **estamos a** 17 grados (centígrados) (Today it is 37ºC)

In case you're referring to the temperature of a person you can use "tener":

> **Tengo** 37 grados de temperatura (I have a temperature of 37ºC)
>
> **Tengo** 37 grados de fiebre (I have a temperature of 37ºC)
>
> **Tengo** fiebre (I have a temperature)

With things we usually use "estar" or "tener una temperatura":

> La lava **está a** 700ºC (the lava has a temperature of 700ºC)
>
> La lava **tiene una temperatura de** 700ºC (the lava has a temperature of 700ºC)

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta aceptada no es exacta del todo. Concretamente:

- *[...] "hace frío" o "hace sol". ¿Es lo mismo con la temperatura?*

**Sí, es lo mismo**. Usando el verbo *hacer* de manera impersonal, **es correcto decir "hace 10 grados"**, [según el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Uv3zo00r8D6awkUI8u):

> **hacer(se).**
>   2. Para expresar circunstancias meteorológicas **o los grados de temperatura atmosférica**, así como cuando se utiliza con expresiones temporales para referirse a un momento situado tanto tiempo atrás como indica el complemento, **funciona como impersonal**, por lo que solo se conjuga en las formas de tercera persona del singular: *«A esa altura de la noche hacía bastante frío»* (Benedetti *Primavera* [Ur. 1982]); ***«Fuera hace 50 grados bajo cero»*** (Ortega *Artículos* [Esp. 1917-33]); *«Hace dos días ha amanecido loco furioso»* (Prada *Hora* [Méx. 1979]). En todos estos casos, es impropio hacer concordar el verbo *hacer* en plural cuando es plural el complemento: *******«De día hacen 10 grados bajo cero» (*Tribuno*<sup>@</sup> [Arg.] 2.99);

- *Si es la temperatura de algo, como una persona o comida, ¿es lo mismo?*

No, el uso del verbo *hacer* para referirse a la temperatura está limitado a la temperatura atmosférica. Para los otros casos que comentas, se usan los verbos indicados en la [respuesta de Javi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1673/13628).